# Problem with Character Set

Tags: oracle10g

I am in a problem because of the character set.
My client sent me a Oracle database 10g. And when i am going to run the scripts on that database it is giving me error that character set mismatch.

I am not an Oracle expert.

Can anyone please let me know What should i do?

Thanks,
Mahesh.

Answer (score 0):

Ask the client what encoding they used in the database, and adjust yours to match? I'm no Oracle expert either, but this is fairly straight forward.